# Express js caching the index page

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

I have created a authentication system in node using express.js. It works fine but when I try to logout, I am redirecting to the index page. "localhost:3100/". When I go there, Sometime it shows the cached with status as logged-in and some time the new-refreshed page. If referesh the page, every thing goes back to normal. If I redirect to a different page then it works fine.
Is it something especial with index page, that app is rendering the cached version.

This is mainly happening when I am changing the content based on res.locals.currentUser. currentUser is being set in the middleware. In Navbar I am using this <% if(currentUser)% >  <%}else{%> <%}%>. So on redirect, sometime it refreshes and some time it uses the cached view.

Also I am using express.js 3.

Comment: How are you redirecting? Are you using `res.redirect('/')`?

Comment: yes, I am redirecting using res.redirect('/')

Answer (score 4):

For your `/` route you want to add a middleware that will force it to always load without caching. Add this:

```
app.use(function noCacheForRoot(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
      res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
      res.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
      res.header("Expires", 0);
    }
    next();
});
```

Place this middleware high up on the list, before your `app.use(app.router)` and  `app.user(express.static(...))` statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is mainly happening when I am changing the content based on res.locals.currentUser. currentUser is being set in the middleware. In Navbar I am using this <% if(currentUser)% > <content> <%}else{%> <content><%}%>. So on redirect, sometime it refreshes and some time it uses the cached view.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are setting a `res.locals.currentUser` and then doing a `res.redirect('/')`. `res.locals` are scoped to the request, thus only available to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle. If you do a redirect, then that is a new request/response cycle and you shouldn't have any `res.locals` from the previous cycle. In the middleware I wrote above, add `console.log("res.locals : ", res.locals)` and see what is printed.

Comment: Above middleware doesn't work for me. I replicate the issue by creating 2 pages with 2 links on each page.
Clicking first link will create session variable and click second link will take you to the next page. On the second page First link will destroy the session variable and second link will take you the first page. 
Once you create the session on the first page, go to the second page, come back to the first page and show some data based on session. again go to the second page, destory the session variable, redirect to first page. you will see the stale data.

Comment: This works fine if you are using a single page app and reloading the page instead of redirect. Reloading will get the fresh-data from the server. Newbie to nodejs, so not sure is this the valid behaviour.